# Firebird check if date is before 12 pm of the current day

Tags: firebird

Date calculations are not my strong point and I need a little help.
I'm trying to check if a date (which is a timestamp) from a selected field is before 12pm of the current day. Thanks in advance.

Scenario: if an order is placed before 12pm that day, it will qualify for x otherwise it gets y. So my create date (including time) of that order is what I get in my select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATE` type doesn't carry time information, so it is up to you to define at what point in time the date is. You should use `TIMESTAMP` type if the time information is also important. 
Anyway, lets say that the field stores the date at 12pm time, then you use

```
WHERE date_field <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

`CURRENT_DATE` is so called  context variable which returns, obviously, current date. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIME` are also available. You can use [DATEADD](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html) and [DATEDIFF](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-datediff.html) builtin functions to do some date calculations.

So if the field is actually timestamp, you could do it like

```
WHERE date_field < DateAdd(12 HOUR to cast(CURRENT_DATE as timestamp));
```

Comment: ain, thanks for the reply. I understand your suggestion about the timestamp however my date field from the selection must be checked if it's before 12pm of CURRENT_DATE/NOW. I'll edit my question to explain the scenario...

Comment: @user2086463 As a `DATE` in Firebird does not have a time portion it is not possible to check if it is before or after '12pm', you will need to use `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: As Mark already wrote, it's not possible with only `DATE` field unless you have the time the order is placed stored into some other field. BTW using `am/pm` is confusing (at least to me), I suggest to use 24 hour clock to make your question clear. I take it you need orders placed before midday of the current day?

Comment: ain, that's correct - midday of the current day. I edited my question to say that the date is actually a timestamp. Sorry for the ambiguous description.

Comment: Yes, that's it. So CURRENT_DATE is actually 19 Feb 2013 12:00 am excluding the time frac?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is just a date, without any time information. But if you cast it to timestamp (which DateAdd does) then yes, the time part is midnight at the start of the day.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help, ain. Simple, yet it totally slipped my mind.

Comment: BTW you actually need to cast the date argument of the `DateAdd` function to timestamp yourself, otherwise the function returns just date too. See my answer.